# Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin Error when loading

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios

when i create a new project for Xamarin in VS 2015 i get this message 
can anybody explain the error ?

please note :

- iam using the latest update for xamarin
- iam choosing cross platform xamarin.form (android and ios)

[image]

Comment: it is missing some specific Xamarin version. I'd just reinstall everything.

Comment: is there any simple solution ?? reinstall vs2015 isn't easy @VladMatvienko

Comment: actually reinstalling is easiest. Alternatively, you can search for the templates, change the default version of Xamarin, but I have no idea where you need to do that. I'd just reinstall. If you will do - first uninstall it completely.

Comment: thanxx @VladMatvienko i will try

Comment: I tried reinstalling VS2015 and same problem !!!!! @VladMatvienko

Comment: Open your visual studio, Tools -> Extensions & Updates -> select updates -> select visual studio gallery then update your nuget package manager.